# Jenkins: Send email based on script output

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have tests automation framework, and the test runs are driven through Jenkins. After the test run is completed, it generates a few custom test reports, as HTML file. In the report, I have a table with a total number of errors as one of the columns. I basically want to parse this HTML file and send out an email to a mailing list if the error is greater than 0.

Here is what I have done till now, in my Jenkins job:

a. Configured the job to run the tests [this is in an execute shell option and running my jar, as the test framework is a java application]
b. I have a post-build action, in which I execute a python code, which does the following:

Step 1. Get the latest HTML report.
Step 2. Parse this file.
Step 3. If the error is > 0:
then email_flag = true
else:
email_flag = false.

Now is there a way I can use the above flags and send email notifications, via Jenkins plugins? I just want to understand the best way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I did some additional research and I see the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) has a pre-send script option, but I just don't know how to use this to run the python code and handle the email messaging.

Answer (score 0):

During your build action - ie  while executing the tests, when you know the test fails in java, immediately or after executing all the tests , you can make java return a value to the shell.

`System.exit(0)`  - Success

`System.exit(1)`  - Failure

Whenever it is not 0, jenkins jobs is marked as Failed by default.

You can use `Email-ext` plugin to send the email only when the job is failed by selecting the appropriate trigger - `Failure - Any`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is my Extended Email Publisher Jenkins plugin pre-send Groovy script. Hope you are able to adjust it to your needs.

It is designed for parsing Serenity-JUnit XML files but with little effort it can parse HTML. It will look for any file in given `sourceDirPath` which match pattern `"SERENITY-JUNIT-*xml"`. It will then `file.readToString()`, extract test results from that `xmlString` and aggregate those results into variables `tests, passed, failures, errors, skipped`. Finally it will compose a `msgSubject` and append it to `msg` itself.

NOTE that `build`, `logger` and `msg` are objects made available by the plugin. You should not change assign them and/or change their names.

Script:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
import org.w3c.dom.Document
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList
import org.w3c.dom.Node
import org.w3c.dom.Element
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import java.io.StringReader

logger.println "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
logger.println "Parsing SERENITY-JUNIT XML files for results to update Editable Email Notification."

// determine if build is remote, list folder and files
def sourceDirPath

if(build.workspace.isRemote()){
    channel = build.workspace.channel
    logger.println "Using channel: " + channel
    sourceDirPath = new FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "\\target\\site\\serenity\\")
} else {
    sourceDirPath = new FilePath(new File(build.workspace.toString() + "\\target\\site\\serenity\\"))
}
logger.println "Source dir: " + sourceDirPath

def files = sourceDirPath.list("SERENITY-JUNIT-*xml")

logger.println "Found XML files: \n" + files

// initialize result variables
def tests = 0
def failures = 0
def errors = 0
def skipped = 0
def passed = 0

// parse files
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
files.each{
    logger.println "Starting to parse file: " + it

    channel = build.workspace.channel
    def file = new FilePath(channel, it.getRemote())
    def xmlString = file.readToString()
    logger.println "Extracted XML:\n" + xmlString

    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder()
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize()
    Element testsuiteNode = doc.getDocumentElement()
    logger.println testsuiteNode

    tests += Integer.parseInt(testsuiteNode.getAttribute("tests"))
    failures += Integer.parseInt(testsuiteNode.getAttribute("failures"))
    errors += Integer.parseInt(testsuiteNode.getAttribute("errors"))
    skipped += Integer.parseInt(testsuiteNode.getAttribute("skipped"))  
    logger.println "Completed parsing file: " + it
}
// calculate passed tests amount
passed = tests - failures - errors - skipped

// aggregated results
logger.println "Aggregated results:"
logger.println "Tests: " + tests
logger.println "Passed: " + passed
logger.println "Failures: " + failures
logger.println "Errors: " + errors
logger.println "Skipped: " + skipped

// compose message subject
def msgSubject
if(tests == 4){
    if(failures > 0 || errors > 0){
        msgSubject = "FAILED - Passed ${passed}/${tests}, Failures ${failures}, Errors ${errors}, Skipped ${skipped}."
    }else if(skipped > 0){
        msgSubject = "OK (w/ skipped tests) - Passed ${passed}/${tests}, Failures ${failures}, Errors ${errors}, Skipped ${skipped}."
    }else{
        msgSubject = "OK - Passed ${passed}/${tests}, Failures ${failures}, Errors ${errors}, Skipped ${skipped}."
    }
}else{
    msgSubject = "FAILED - Not all tests or too many tests executed (${tests})."
}

// set message subject
msg.setSubject(msg.getSubject() + ": " + msgSubject)

logger.println "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

You may of course dynamically change any element of the email (To, From, MsgText, etc.). Here I am only changing the subject.

The result is something like:

**Wellness Check: OK - Passed 4/4, Failures 0, Errors 0, Skipped 0.**